# How can jekyll judge whether it is a page or a post?

Tags: html, if-statement, jekyll, liquid

I want to add a class to the body tag using if sentence, if the page is a post then add page to the class if the page is a post then add post to it. I don't know in specific how to do this, can anyone help me figure it out?

Comment: I've done it before by checking to see if there's a date associated with the page, since, generally speaking, only posts have dates.

Comment: This question should not have been closed as "too localized"; I know I have wondered this very same thing before, and I'm sure others have, too.

Answer (score 15):

You can test for the presence of `page.date` or `page.id`, e.g.

```
<div class="{% if page.id %} post {% else %} page {% endif %}">
   ...
</div>
```